# Android - Scroll View

Tags: android

For my app I have a screen which has the layout of

```
<Linear Layout>
  <RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout>
```

Within these Relative Layouts is the content of the page, however in one of them there is the following

```
  <RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
```

I want this content to be scrollable however the app is crashing stating that the scrollable view can only have one child item, is there anyway around this?

EDIT XML as requested

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2.27"
    >



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/Combo_FlavChoice1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:entries="@array/VGPG_combo"
            />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/Combo_InvChoice1"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/Text_Perc1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="8sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/Combo_FlavChoice2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:entries="@array/VGPG_combo" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/Combo_InvChoice2"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/Text_Perc2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="8sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/Combo_FlavChoice3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:entries="@array/VGPG_combo" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/Combo_InvChoice3"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/Text_Perc3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="8sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT - This is how the view should look like

[image: Original]

Now:

[image: Now]

Comment: Can you share your xml?

Comment: Where is the ScrollView?

Comment: Removed it out as it was causing errors!

Comment: I think a good alternative solution would be, to use a Listview....

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html):

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

You just need to wrap your outer RelativeLayout in a ScrollView. Also it looks like you are placing 3 LinearLayouts on top of each other in that RelativeLayout, it may be better to just place them in a LinearLayout and make the height of that wrap_content?

Answer (score 0):

Add a LinearLayout to your ScrollView and fill that one with your RelativeLayouts. Something like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

           <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            add your stuff here

           </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hi @Helix I done what you advised however now my Linear Layouts that are in the relative Layout are on top of each other and won't line up one under the other, I'll update my question with screenshots